# API Testing Using SoapUI vs Postman vs Runscope

Tags: automated-tests, soapui, postman, web-api-testing, runscope

I'm new to using applications to test backend APIs. I've always just manually tested using the front-end applications. What I would like to do is to use an app that is designed specifically for backend API testing. So far, I've been directed to SoapUI, Postman, and Runscope. But I'm at a loss as I am more of a test analyst than I am a programmer, despite having experience automated testing in Selenium with JavaScript, Python and Ruby. Any suggestions? Thoughts? Warnings?

(I posted this to the QA page, too, so sorry for the duplicate question)

Answer (score 10):

SoapUI is not a paid tool. It has a Open Source community version also. It is also platform independent.
I am a great fan of Soap-UI and I feel there are no justifications from any one to not to use SoapUI.

When choosing SoapUI, it is not just about writing tests. If you have a wsdl/wadl description file available then you can import them and you will be able to auto generate tests for your API's without any effort and your life will be lot easier.

It has lot of plugins available to easily integrate with emerging trends around API's like Swagger, RAML, API BluePrint and CA developer Portal, JIRA etc. Also the Support the you are going to get from SoapUI community is going to be awesome.

Comment: SoapUI NG Pro is the paid version, SoapUI is the open source version. See https://www.soapui.org/

Answer (score 2):

API testing can be done by preparing the framework in Java and selenium+behat can be utilized there.

SOAPUI and Runscope are the paid tools ,but time will be saved in API testing.

Postman is generally used for debugging the issues.
For more details, please go through, https://www.qasource.com/api-testing.php