# What is the major difference between SoapUI and Postman? & which one to prefer for testing REST APIs?

Tags: rest, soapui, postman, web-api-testing

We are analysing the best tool to test REST APIs. Also considering in mind, integration with TFS.

Comment: What are your observations?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [API Testing Using SoapUI vs Postman vs Runscope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30645751/api-testing-using-soapui-vs-postman-vs-runscope)

Answer (score 11):

Some basic starter differences:-
Postman is lightweight browser based tool. easy to use, easy to share tests b/w team members by export option,

SoapUI is also easy to use with SoapUI you integrate it with GIT/SVN directly for Checkin and checkout your scripts.

SoapUI supports Groovy Scripting, Postman don't
for basic test scenarios you can use postman, if there is a need for logical based decision making calls SoapUI is best.

Comment: as of very recently the chrome plugin is deprecated, and you should use the local application